# Nested Variables in Jinja2/Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, nested-lists

I am struggling to understand how to use nested variables in Jinja2/Ansible

I have the following Variables in a yaml file

```yaml
dual_homed_workloads:
  switch1:
    - tag: 200
      description: DB-Servers
      ports:
      lags: [1,2,4]
    - tag: 201
      description: Storage
      ports:
      lags: [1,2,4]
    - tag: 202
      description: iLo
      ports:
      lags: [1,3,4]
  switch2:
    - tag: 200
      description: DB-Servers
      ports:
      lags: [3,4]
    - tag: 211
      description: voice
      ports:
      lags: [1,]
    - tag: 2000
      description: egree
      ports:
      lags: [2,3]
```

and I want to search for the switch name matching the `inventory_hostname`, then get the tag of the VLAN

```
{% for vlan, switch in dual_homed_workloads %}
{% if switch == inventory_hostname %}
VLAN {{ vlan.tag }}
  name {{ vlan.descrption }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I was to run this for switch 1 I'd want an output as follows

```
vlan 200
 name DB-Servers
vlan 201
 name Storage
vlan 202
 name iLo
```

Also the LAGs is a list, is there a way of searching that list for a value e.g. `"1"`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will loop other all vlans for the switch key equal to current `inventory_hostname` filtering out all vlans which do no contain `1` in the `lags` list:

```
{% for vlan in dual_homed_workloads[inventory_hostname] if 1 in vlan.lags %}
VLAN {{ vlan.tag }}
  name {{ vlan.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here are 2 variations since I don't know exactly what you intend to look for inside the `lags` key.

Keep vlans which are in either `lags` 1 or 2:

```
{% for vlan in dual_homed_workloads[inventory_hostname] if vlan.lags | intersect([1,2]) | length > 0 %}
VLAN {{ vlan.tag }}
  name {{ vlan.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

Only keep vlans which are lags 1 and 2:

```
{% set keep_lags = [1,2] %}
{% for vlan in dual_homed_workloads[inventory_hostname] if vlan.lags | intersect(keep_lags) | length == keep_lags | length %}
VLAN {{ vlan.tag }}
  name {{ vlan.description }}
{% endfor %}
```